# check if a date falls in the last week using date.js

Tags: javascript, datejs

i use [date.js](https://github.com/datejs) for doing certain date calculations.

i am able to find if the date falls in this week, the following returns true

```
dateFld.between(Date.monday(), Date.friday())
```

but I want to check if date falls in the previous week.

i am using the following code without luck.

```
alert(dateFld.between(Date.last().week().monday(), Date.last().week().sunday()));
```

please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sunday is the first day of the week.

Date.last().week().monday()

Mon Sep 07 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time) **Correct**

Date.last().week().sunday()

Sun Sep 06 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time) **Incorrect**

**Date.last().sunday()**

Sun Sep 13 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time) **Correct**